# Storing a file system view in a DB/memory for optimal retrieval

Tags: filesystems, memcached

I have a file system view stored in a file.
Entries like
`/a/b/c/e/file1.txt /a/b/c/e/file2.txt /a/b/c/e/file3.txt /a/k/file4.txt /a/l/file5.txt /m`
When time comes I would like to expose this view to consumer on request. There are multiple view like this stored on separate files. So when user ask for particular views. Backend system needs to serve this request.
A file can have million of entries.

Assuming API(s) request, response would look like,
`request: /a/? response: a/b, a/k, a/l request: /a/b/c/e? response: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt`
My question is how to do I serve this view efficiently?

I can preload a lightweight database say sqlite. Then I can maintain parent->childs relationship for every directory. Index on the parents. Things should work smoothly but dealing with million entries will degrade initial performance and hence user experience.

We can iterate though the file breadth first way. And store it in DB. In parallel we can start serving requests. If entry is not available in DB, we go search the file. Just like caching.

Can you suggest how to make this better? Any designs you would recommend.

Comment: Why not just mount the filesystem over NFS to all the nodes and use regular filesystem operations? Your question might need to be more specific.